# NSCFString leak inVolving NSString

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I am getting leak at:

```
NSString *firstNameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",firstNameString];
```

CODE:

```
+(NSString *)getValueForProperty:(ABPropertyID)propertyId
                      forContact:(NSString *)contactId 
{
    if (addressBook == nil)
    {
        addressBook  = ABAddressBookCreate();
    }
    ABRecordID contactIntId = [contactId intValue];
    ABRecordRef person;
    person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, contactIntId);

    CFStringRef firstName;
    char *firstNameString;
    firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, propertyId);

    // Paso a char* los datos para que se puedan escribir
    static char* fallback = "";
    int fbLength = strlen(fallback);

    int firstNameLength = fbLength;
    bool firstNameFallback = true;

    if (firstName != NULL)
    {
        firstNameLength = (int) CFStringGetLength(firstName);
        firstNameFallback = false;
    }

    if (firstNameLength == 0)
    {
        firstNameLength = fbLength;
        firstNameFallback = true;
    }

    firstNameString = malloc(sizeof(char)*(firstNameLength+1));
    if (firstNameFallback == true)
    {
        strcpy(firstNameString, fallback);
    }
    else
    {
        CFStringGetCString(firstName, firstNameString,
             10*CFStringGetLength(firstName), kCFStringEncodingASCII);
    }

    if (firstName != NULL)
    {
        CFRelease(firstName);
    }

    NSString *firstNameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",firstNameString];

    free(firstNameString);

    return firstNameStr;
}
```

Comment: It looks like most of this method is converting a CFStringRef to an NSString. That’s actually not necessary. All you need to do is cast the CFStringRef to an NSString. Cocoa’s toll-free bridging allows the two to be used interchangeably.

You do need to make sure the value returned from ABRecordCopyValue is actually a string. You can use `CFGetTypeID(firstName) == CFStringGetTypeID()` to make sure the returned value is a CFStringRef, then you can cast it to an NSString with `NSString *value = (NSString *)firstName`.

Answer (score 4):

That means that the *object allocated at that point is leaked*.   In this case, most likely because you over-retained it somewhere and failed to `release` it.

You need to carefully examine the lifespan of that particular string and figure out where you might be overwriting the reference without a release.

**Build & Analyze** might help considerably.